# How can I make a "Go to Desktop" keyboard shortcut in kubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I had a look in **Settings->System settings->Common appearance and behaviour->Shortcuts and Gestures->Standard Keyboard Shortcuts** but I didn't see an option to reach the desktop (nor to minimize every window, which would also work)

I know I can do it at home (Ubuntu 11.04) without trouble using Ctrl+Alt+D but I can't find anything at work where I have KDE 4.5.3

**Update**: For now, I've assigned the following command to "Super+D" : `dolphin ~username/Desktop &`
I would prefer a command which would minimize all windows, effectively revealing the desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: If anyone can give me a one-liner to get my ubuntu version here at work, that would be great.. Can't seem to find it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

---

It seems like you've come from Windows, so here's another tip you may find useful:

You can set lower right corner of the screen to show the desktop. Just go to *Screen Edges* KDE Control Module. It can be found in Kickoff menu by typing "edge".

Comment: The "Screen Edges" trick worked. I have no clue what the "Show the Desktop Plasmoid" is, nor how to put is somewhere, nor how to change its keyboard shortcut setting though..

Comment: @Shawn: Changed the instruction to step-by-step screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

> System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KDE
>   component: KWin > Show Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. One of those should work.

Comment: These don't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I ended up "solving" my problem by assigning the following command to "Super+D":

```
dolphin path/to/Desktop &
```

It's not ideal as it un-necessarily opens a new dolphin instance (which I always close immediately after), but at least I get quick access to my Desktop through a keyboard shortcut.

If someone has a way of accessing the actual Desktop, I would gladly accept that answer instead.